# Can not complete GET request to my localhost or to my external API (express app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am building a React app to consume an API that I built using express.js. My React app successfully gets data using fetch or axios to query data using an official API ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"), but I keep getting an error when I try to get from my own API ("XXX.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/users") or from my localhost ("http://localhost:81/api/v1/users").

**Questions**
Is my GET request wrong?
Is there a problem with the return from my API?
Would you recommend any resources to learn to create a RESTful API with Express.js, set it up in AWS and consume this API with a React app?

Thank you!

---

The error is:

> Access to fetch at 'XXX.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

---

Using `fetch`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch
      ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      // ('XXX.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/users')
      // ('http://localhost:81/api/v1/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          title: data.title,
          body: data.body
        })
      );
  }
```

Using `axios`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data }))
   // .get('http://localhost:81/api/v1/users', { crossDomain: true }).then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data }))
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
      });
  }
```

Comment: As the error suggests, the problem with your express server, read about CORS policy

Comment: You can read express cors documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: That's a server-side problem, nothing has to do with your ```fetch``` or ```axios``` request.

Comment: Thank you, guys. @TitusSutioFanpula, the cors package indeed solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually a cors issue in express, so to solve it add the following in the start file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```